# How to use LESS variable in React JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have the following tag with a hard-coded color:

```
<p style={{ color: '#646464' }}>
```

I want to use a LESS variable that I've defined instead, let's called it `@tertiary-col`, how would I use this variable? `<p style={{ color: '@tertiary-col' }}>` doesn't seem to work

Comment: Is it scss/less variable or a native css variable?

Comment: `<p style={{ color: tertiary-col }}>`  .. .but I dont think "tertiary-col" is a valid variable name

Comment: @shmotam hi yes sorry I meant LESS not CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use variables from CSS-precompilers like LESS inside of your JSX. You can either use JavaScript variables like

```
const redColor = "#FF0000";

<p style={{ color: redColor }}
```

Or give it a `className` and let your CSS handle the rest.

Another option would be to add a loader like [less-vars-to-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-vars-to-js) to map your LESS variables (I'm assuming you mean LESS as you're using `@`) to JavaScript.

And another option would be to use [native CSS variables](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp) as other answers suggested, you can use these variables within your JavaScript, the downside on this is that they [aren't supported by all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) (yet).

Comment: You could AFAIK use a native CSS property `color: --some-css-var` on browsers that support it.

Comment: IE11 is the only browser that does not support `@var`.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to use native `var()` to do this.

By placing the variable in `:root` then it becomes available anywhere you need to use it.

You would do `--tertiary-col: @tertiary-col;`, but for the purposes of the snippet I have put in an actual hex value.

```css
:root {
  --tertiary-col: @tertiary-col; /* this is what you would do */
  --tertiary-col: #646464; /* @tertiary-col; */
}
```

```html
<p style="color: var(--tertiary-col)">Some text</p>
```

Here is an excellent tutorial on css variables: https://codepen.io/abcretrograde/full/xaKVNx/

Answer (score 1):

For using native css variables in React:

Let's say you want to toggle between light and dark themes for any text nodes in a certain element:

```
const LightDarkSpan = ({ children }) => (
  <span style={{
    color: 'var(--text-color, black)'
  }}>
    {children}
  </span>
);
```

Then, any parent can set that variable, and it effectively acts as context to any child element that explicitly chooses to use that specific CSS variable:

```
// rendered
<div style={{
  backgroundColor: 'black',
  '--text-color': 'white'
}}>
  <article>
    <LightDarkSpan>testing</LightDarkSpan>
  </article>
</div>
```

[Reference](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6411#issuecomment-290536512)