# Import .less variables to use within React Styled Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, less, styled-components

I'm trying to import `.less`variables from a file to use within a `styled-component`. Is this possible?

**Variables.less**

```
@color1: #e6ae11;
@color2: #d1e4f7;
```

**Component.jsx**

```
import  '../../../../stylesheets/variables.less';
....
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  text-align: right;
  color: @color1
`;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use LESS variable in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946600/how-to-use-less-variable-in-react-js)

Comment: I personally use less modules in my stack (css modules using less), which allows you to pass everything from a less file to js. [Here's an article with further details on how to set it up](https://medium.com/@joseph0crick/react-css-modules-less-webpack-4-a50d902d0a3)

Comment: My appologies, it's early morning here. I spaced on mixing the `LESS` and `CSS`, which I don't actually want to do. I will be sticking with using `.less`  files for this situation. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. I guess you use Webpack, you just need to configure webpack loaders so that when an `import '*.less'` is found, it :

- compiles less into css
- setups the css to be a css module

The webpack configuration looks like this :

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "less-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Source : [here](https://medium.com/@joseph0crick/react-css-modules-less-webpack-4-a50d902d0a3)

Note that when configuring webpack loaders, the loaders (in the `use` array) are called in reverse order at compile time.